# Magically Incremented column ID after deployment on Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a strange issue, I deployed my application to production. Application is working fine. I have uploaded database too with some local data. After one day, database ID are incremented by 10000. I don't know why and how. See below picture. Blue ones are from local environment and yellow ones are of production.

Moreover when I connect to the production server and try to open any tables for edit I get an error:

> This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)

If this increment some how connected to this ?

[image]

Comment: Are these ids with yellow background newly created records on production?

Comment: It looks like you inserted 10000 records then deleted them in that table in that copy of the database.

Comment: Yes, yellow one belong to Production entries.

Comment: @drewlander no we didtnt delete any entries

Comment: A rollback could cause gaps too.  You just need to check fk constraints and reseed it if it's possible

Comment: I get what you are saying now.  So your increment jumped 9998 rows.  I dont think that would be related to the editor because I dont know how many rows MS Vis DB tools opens to edit, but its probably not divisible by that number.  SSMS allows edit top 200, which I suspect is the same as MS VisDB Tools.

Comment: If you care about the actual numerical values for such columns, you're using them wrong. You should treat them as opaque blobs that happen to fit in numeric columns for the purposes of storage. You shouldn't be showing them to users. At a guess, in production you're in some form of replicated environment, where each replication server takes ranges of identity values in chunks so that they can independently assign identity values without having to communicate for every insert.

Comment: This happened to me too the last time I deployed the database to Azure.  As my ID were all in a similar range as DDR's (less than 1000) and my ID column is of type BIGINT, the solution was to just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Microsoft considers this a "feature" and not a bug. According to the site I found explaining it, SQL Server will do this when the server is restarted (perhaps to prevent duplicate IDs?) and the amount of the increment depends on the data type of the column, so an INT field will jump by 1,000 and a BIGINT will jump by 10,000.

Read here for more information, but essentially if you care about the value of your identity column than don't use an identity column and instead create a sequence of numbers.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-2012-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012 has a new identity implementation that is shared with `SEQUENCE`. This unfortunate behavior is intentional.

[Enable trace flag 272 on startup.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/)

> Use trace flag 272. This will cause a log record to be
>   generated for each generated identity value. The performance of
>   identity generation may be impacted by turning on this trace flag. •
>   Use a sequence generator with the NO CACHE
>   setting(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) o This
>   will cause a log record to be generated for each generated sequence
>   value. Note that the performance of sequence value generation may be
>   impacted by using NO CACHE.

Don't rely on identity values to be consecutive. Still, these large jumps are annoying im many small ways.